# Is it possible to use a BLE enabled Android/iPhone as a BLE beacon?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I'm working on a BLE proximity sensing feature based on Android and need some information.
Currently I see there are no BLE beacons manufacturers for android. I found 2 so far for iPhone.
1) http://www.estimote.com
2) http://www.gimbal.com

Estimote claims that their devices are generic but mainly they are publicized for iBeacons. So I'm not sure whether I should order them for a feature on Android.
Secondly gimbal explicitly mentions that their devices won't be enabled for android for proximity sensing.

So if any of you know where can I order BLE beacons compatible with Android please let me know.

Another thing, for prototype testing I was wondering whether I could use a Android BLE capable tablet or smartphone as a beacon to emit BLE signals?
Till now the documentation for android only suggests how to detect a beacon, But I'm not sure whether an Android device can be used as a beacon.
Any insights?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**There is a BLE Beacon manufacturer for Android: [Radius Networks](http://www.radiusnetworks.com)**

You can detect any standard iBeacon on Android using our [Android iBeacon Library.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/)

You can try it out yourself with our free [iBeacon Locate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconlocate&hl=en), which is based on this library.  My company also sells both [software and hardware iBeacons](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/ibeacon-development-kit.html) that I guarantee work with Android.  But again, any standard iBeacon will work, too.  Don't take my word for it -- just download our free app and use it to see one of our iBeacons.  (We even have a [free virtual machine](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/virtual.html) you can use!)

It is currently not possible to make an iBeacon out of a stock Android device because the Bluetooth LE APIs, introduced in Android 4.3, do not support the **peripheral mode** needed to transmit advertisements like an iBeacon.

**EDIT:** It is now possible to make rooted Android 4.4.3 devices transmit as an iBeacon.  See [here.](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/building-android-beacon-android-ibeacon-tutorial-overview/)

Answer (score 1):

I tried simple BLE scan app on Android, but the callback for LeDevices always returned null for UUID[]. Also, finding based on know UUID didnot work.

To add to David's reply. I have tried Radius Networks SDK, pretty clean. I like it.

Also, Estimotes has released their Android SDK today(1/7), which is good. The sample App shows notification, Distance, Major-Minor. I tested with 3 Estimotes & also with iPhone's app (making the iPhone as iBeacon). It works well, give it a try.
Note that you have to modify the code 
change the ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID value to the UUID that you are watching for.

Hope it helps.